# Sed removing instances of log errors from a file, but only if the file doesn't exist?

Tags: bash, sed

**Please note:** this is purely a bash scripting and `sed` question, even though it mentions a few other technologies (MySQL, Docker, etc.) in passing, for context.

---

Looking at a [bash script](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh) that runs when the official [MySQL 8.0 Dockerfile](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/tree/mysql-server/8.0) builds, I see this:

```
if [ -n "$MYSQL_LOG_CONSOLE" ] || [ -n "console" ]; then
  # Don't touch bind-mounted config files
  if ! cat /proc/1/mounts | grep "etc/my.cnf"; then
    sed -i 's/^log-error=/#&/' /etc/my.cnf
  fi
fi
```

...and I'm trying to make sense of what it does. A few things don't make sense to me, but this is from the official MySQL Docker project, so obviously they know what they're doing. It *looks* like its saying:

1. check to see if a string variable called `MYSQL_LOG_CONSOLE` is not null, or if the hard-coded string literal "console" is not null
2. If either are true, and then search available mount info (`proc/1/mounts`) to see if `etc/my.cnf` is referenced in it
3. If `etc/my.cnf` is not contained inside of `proc/1/mounts`, then remove all instances of `log-error` from inside `etc/my.cnf`

To start with, what's the point of checking whether the string literal "console" is null or not with `[ -n "console" ]`? How could a non-null string literal ever be...null?

But the main question I have though is with the `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/^log-error=/#&/' /etc/my.cnf
```

**Am I interpreting this `sed` command correctly?** Remove all instance of `log-error` from the file...if the file doesn't exist?! I'm clearly missing something, just not sure what. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have a problem understanding the Bash script, check it at https://www.shellcheck.net/. The sed `sed -i 's/^log-error=/#&/' /etc/my.cnf` command just prepends the line starting with `log-error=` with a `#` char (comments it out).

Comment: -n is checking that the strings are not null as opposed to checking if they are null (-z). So if the console setting is instigated with an environmental variable, don't amend and file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what's the point of checking whether the string literal "console" is null or not with [ -n "console" ]?

The file is generated from the [template](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/template/docker-entrypoint.sh#L49):

> ```
> if [ -n "$MYSQL_LOG_CONSOLE" ] || [ -n "%%DEFAULT_LOG%%" ]; then
> ```

Logging to console is by default enabled only in mysql 8, from [generating script](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-docker/blob/mysql-server/gen_dockerfiles.sh#L77):

> ```
> declare -A DEFAULT_LOG
> DEFAULT_LOG["5.6"]=""
> DEFAULT_LOG["5.7"]=""
> DEFAULT_LOG["8.0"]="console"
> ```

> How could a non-null string literal ever be...null?

It cannot be.

> Am I interpreting this sed command correctly?

No. The `sed` command doesn't remove the lines, it prepends `#` in front of the lines starting with `log-error=`.

> Remove all instance of log-error from the file...

No.

> if the file doesn't exist?!

No, only if the file is not mounted.